# Unable to access app angular + nginx + istio

Tags: angular, nginx, kubernetes, istio

I am trying to configure istio service mesh for a project consisting of .net core services with angular 6 as front end.

Funny thing is that if i deploy application with build and run inside docker applications are running fine.

**Example:** angular serving with prod or qa configuration inside node image.

But application will not work if i use nginx image by copying dist folder content inside html folder.

**NOTE: Istio configuration is in place.**

I created destination rule, virtual service for the angular with nginx deployment with

1. Nodeport :

   **upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure**
2. ClusterIp:

   **Request not reaching service**
3. Loadbalancer

   **Request not reaching**

Tried overriding default.conf of nginx as mentioned in [Envoy not connecting](https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/#envoy-won-t-connect-to-my-http-1-0-service) but file is not getting overwritten.

Comment: Could You please provide destination rule, virtual service, nginx yamls?

Comment: Hi @jt97 , i found the issue, it is due to nginx upstream and port configuration in nginx.conf/default.conf. I am attaching conf need to be used for conf.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after doing lot of research.

As mentioned in istio documentation [nginx upstream error](https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/), i made changes in my nginx.conf as below.

> ```
> upstream application {
>   server 0.0.0.0:[PortNumber];
> }
>
> server {
>   listen [PortNumber] default_server;
>
>   charset utf-8;
>
>   sendfile on;
>
>   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
>
>   #Caches static assets
>   location ~ ^/(assets|bower_components|scripts|styles|views) {
>     expires     31d;
>     add_header  Cache-Control public;
>   }
>
>   #Caches Bundles created by angular cli
>   location ~* \.(?:bundle.js|bundle.css)$ {
>     expires 1M;
>     access_log off;
>     add_header Cache-Control "public";
>   }
>
>   ##
>   # Main file index.html sending not found locations to the main
>   ##
>   location / {
>     proxy_pass http://application;
>     proxy_http_version 1.1;
>     proxy_set_header Connection "";
>     expires -1;
>     add_header Pragma "no-cache";
>     add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
>
>     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html = 404;
>   }
> }
> ```